# Is it possible to tell Rollup to place the licenses in another file instead of putting it in the main bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, licensing, rollupjs

So whenever I use something like **Vite** which uses **Rollup** under the hood, I always find that the licenses for the npm packages I use are embedded directly into the bundle.

But, if I try to bundle my code with something like Webpack, it puts the License in another text file. I noticed that the bundle size difference was considerably between both.

If I create an app with **React, Lodash & Moment**, the webpack one comes out to be **20-40kib** smaller than the rollup version:

Heres what I mean for a simple app that only uses **React**:

```js
// This is literally the entire thing it has to bundle:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const a = React;
const b = ReactDOM.createRoot;
```

Now if I bundle it with webpack, it creates a seperate license file:

[image: Bundle with Webpack]

And the main bundle is about 132kb.

BUT, if I run the same thing with **Vite & Rollup**, here is the result I get: 

[image: Vite with Rollup]

And the licenses themselves are embedded directly into the bundle:

[image: License]

And the bundle size is around 138-140kbs.
Now yes, these are fine for small applications, but for larger applications with a ton of dependecies, this might cause an issue where **40-60kbs** of JS is just licenses. 
Which can cause in increased page load time.

So I basically want that Rollup Splits the Licenses into its own txt file (like webpack). 
Is it possible to do though?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to do that. Have a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-license

Install the package with `npm install rollup-plugin-license`

In `vite.config.js` add `import license from 'rollup-plugin-license'`

Then add the following code to the plugins-Config:

```
plugins: [
  license({
    thirdParty: {
      output: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'dependencies.txt'),
      includePrivate: true, // Default is false.
    },
  })
]
```

This will create a File (`dependencies.txt`) when building, containing all the licenses.

Comment: mind showing how to use it to solve this particular problem?